# can i turn string into a variable?

Tags: java, android

i have a assets class that has loaded all of my images, i also have a card class and i have a string in the card class for the name of that card. now i wanted to draw that image from the value in my  assets with the string from the card class so they match up.  how would i accomplish this ?

this is what i have

```
class Assets {
       public static Pixmap kick;
}
```

and the context i wanna get it from

```
void drawHand(){
        int x = 70;
        for(int i=0;i<hand.length;i++){
            Graphics g = game.getGraphics();
            g.drawPixmap(Assets.(hand[i].returnname()),x,230); // hand[i].returnname() == "kick"
            x= x+65 ;
        }

    }
```

Comment: If you're saying you want to set things up so that `hand[i].returnname()` returns the string `"kick"` and then it would load `Assets.kick`, you can't do that in Java.  You want to set up a `Map<String,Pixmap>` to associate the `String` `"kick"` with the desired `Pixmap`, instead of (or in addition to) a variable named `kick`.  See this [javadoc for `Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).

Comment: @ajb False. You can do it using reflection. But you're right about the fact that whatever he wants to achieve - it can be done more easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the class member names using reflection:

```
class Assets {
    public Integer kick = 5;
}

class HelloWorld
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Assets t = new Assets();
        Field[] fields = t.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field f: fields){
            System.out.println("f = " + f.getName()); // prints f = kick
        }
    }
}
```

That said, I agree with @ajb: you probably want to use a hashmap, further, usually it's a good idea to avoid using reflection.